# Locale specific swagger api documentation in springboot?

Tags: spring-boot, localization, internationalization, swagger, springfox

In my springboot project, I have used Swagger for API documentation, Now my requirement is to provide different locale support like Spanish, French, Japanese etc

Till now, I am reading my swagger documentaion from one property file like this

```
@ApiOperation(value="${get.value}", notes="${get.notes}")
```

And this get.value and get.notes I have defined in swagger.properties file and have registered that file as in @Configuration annotated class.

```
@PropertySource("classpath:swagger.properties")
```

Now how can I extend it further to support **different locales**?
I have gone through many links but unable to find anything suitable, please guide.
Thanks

Comment: is it springdoc or springfox?

Comment: springfox
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested a solution, but I would have thought you could do something with profiles here. Load in a different properties file based on a profile that is specific for language, as Spring supports multiple profiles it can be quite clean.

e.g.

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=development,en
-Dspring.profiles.active=development,fr
```